# HTML & CSS: aside/section alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

On some of my pages, the section is longer than my aside. I don't want to alter the length of my aside because that would make some pages unnecessarily long for the short content on the page.

My issue is that once my section gets past the length of my aside, the text goes all the way to the left below my aside. I want to keep it going straight down so it is all in line. Make sense?

I can't seem to find the right CSS to make this happen. Can anyone help?

```css
aside {
  float: left;
  width: 155px;
  height: 200px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

aside ul {
  padding-left: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  /* Removes bullets from list items */
}

aside li {
  margin-bottom: 0.50em;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

aside li a {
  display: block;
  /* Makes whole box clickable */
  padding: .5em 1em;
  /* Space around text */
  text-decoration: none;
  /* Removes underlines */
  color: black;
}

aside a.current {
  color: green;
}

/* Section */

#learnin {
  color: purple;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-family: "Courier", monospace;
  width: 700px;
}

section img {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

section li img {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

section {padding: 5px 20px;/* top right bottom left */}
section ul {padding-left: 0px;}
section p {padding-right: 10px;}
section h3 {
  clear;
  both;

}

section li {
  margin-left: 12em;
}

section a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: blue !important;
}

img.smiles {
  clear: all;
  float: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.nested {
  clear: all;
  margin-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="link3.html">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>

<section>
  <p>[text] ...
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: Show us your code :) How can anybody help without seeing what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe define a width for your Section?
Show your code please.

Comment: Ksu - I tried that. I added my code above.

Comment: Try giving just the section div float:left and a specific width.....also you can upload your code using jsfiddle